# vb.net read binary file

Tags: vb.net, binary, byte

This is what I use in VB5. How can I do the same thing in VB.net (2015)?

With all the variables dimensioned the following VB5 code reads the first four bytes in a binary file opened as #2 to fill the li(4) array.

```
For i = 1 To 4
mychar = InputB(1, #2) 'Get one character.
li(i) = AscB(mychar)
Next
```

Then I call my liconvert(a,b,c,d) function to get the long integer number
represented by the first four bytes in the file and return that number as “t”

```
t = Val(liconvert(li(1), li(2), li(3), li(4)))
```

What I would do from here takes a lot more code. I just need to get this far.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.read(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Once you have called `FileStream.Read` to get the first four `byte`s from the file, you can use the `BitConverter` class to convert those four `byte`s to a `long`.

Answer (score 2):

With the start I got from you I did more looking and found this code which seems to do exactly what I need.

```
Public Sub ReadBinaryII()
' Get the file name.
Dim file_name As String = "xxx.xxx"
' Open the file.
Dim fs As New FileStream(file_name, FileMode.Open)
' Create a BinaryReader for the FileStream.
Dim binary_reader As New BinaryReader(fs)
fs.Position = 0
' Read the data as a byte array.
Dim bytes() As Byte = binary_reader.ReadBytes(20)
' Print the byte data to a text box
myForm.Txt1.Text = bytes(0) & "/" & bytes(1) & "/" & bytes(2) & "/" & bytes(3)
binary_reader.Close()
fs.Dispose()
End Sub
```

Any cautions or additions? Thanks so much!

Comment: I would recommend creating your readers and file streams inside a Using block so they are automatically closed/disposed when you are finished with them.

Comment: Thanks Chris. I'll do that.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to jmcilhinney's comment, you can use the `BinaryReader` to read values from a file.  See this example:

```
Public Sub ReadBinary()
    Using strm As New FileStream("c:\test\filename.bin", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite)
        Using rdr As New BinaryReader(strm)
            'Read integer and byte vaules from the file
            Dim i As Integer = rdr.ReadInt32()
            Dim l As Long = rdr.ReadInt64()
            Dim b As Byte = rdr.ReadByte()

            'Read 100 bytes from the file
            Dim bytes(99) As Byte
            Dim bytesRead As Integer = rdr.Read(bytes, 0, 100)
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

`BinaryReader` has other methods besides the ones shown here.

Comment: Thanks. Didn't quite work. I copied the code replacing the filename with my own path/file and added a text box to display the value of "bytesRead". When I called the Sub the textbox just shows the value "100". If I change the "(bytes,0,100)" to "(bytes,0,4)" the text box shows "4". What I need is a way for the routine to read the file and get the ASCII values of each byte in the file sequentially. For example if the Binary file started out as "aq7B...." I could fill an array with the ASCII equivalents which are 97,113,7,66. I'm sure I'm close but missing something.

Comment: Ok now I see what I've done. My text box is just displaying the number of bytes read from the file, DUH!. How do I get the ASCII values of the bytes into an array?

Comment: Ok. I've got it partially figured out. The bytes(99) array does hold the characters from the binary file. That's what I need. However, for some reason byte(0) is actually the 15th byte in my file. I'm trying to figure that one out.

Comment: In the example code, reading the Int32 advances the file pointer 4 bytes, the Int64 advances it by 8, and the Byte would advance it another 1 byte so by the time the `Read` is called for the array, the file pointer should be on the 14th byte.